# Why can’t I initialize a Swift UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt32> with (&myUInt32) or (&[myUInt32])

Tags: swift, pointers, initializer

The docs say: "When a function is declared as taking an UnsafeMutablePointer argument, it can accept any of the following...   An in-out expression whose operand is a stored lvalue of type Type, which is passed as the address of the lvalue."
I can copy the example and demonstrate this.

```
func takesAMutablePointer<T>(x: UnsafeMutablePointer<T>) -> UnsafeMutablePointer<T>
    {
        return x
    }

func useAMutablePointer()
    {
        var legInt :UInt32 = 42
        var legIntArray: [UInt32] = [legInt]
        var legIntPtr: UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt32>
        legIntPtr = takesAMutablePointer(&legInt)
        legIntPtr = takesAMutablePointer(&legIntArray)
        legIntPtr = UnsafeMutablePointer(&legInt) //Compile error!
        legIntPtr = UnsafeMutablePointer(&legIntArray) //Compile error!
    }
```

Xcode shows that UnsafeMutablePointer has the following initializer:

`init<U>(_ from: UnsafeMutablePointer<U>)` 
, but when I try to use it like my function, the compiler error is `Cannot find an initializer for type 'UnsafeMutablePointer<T>' that accepts an argument list of type '(inout UInt32)'`
So,

1. What's the direct way to get an `UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt32>` to legInt?
2. Why can’t I use the initializer as expected?

Thanks!

Comment: There is no direct way. There are some workarounds but there are no direct ways. Swift support pointers only to provide interoperability with C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am a little bit speculating here, but the reason seems to be that
`UnsafeMutablePointer<T>` has *generic* initializer

```
init<U>(_ from: UnsafeMutablePointer<U>)
```

where `<U>` is unrelated to `<T>`. It seems that the compiler cannot
infer the type `<U>` in

```
legIntPtr = UnsafeMutablePointer(&legInt) //Compile error!
```

Just to confirm this conjecture, we can define a custom extension

```
extension UnsafeMutablePointer {
    init(_ from : UnsafeMutablePointer<T>) {
    // Swift 2: init(_ from : UnsafeMutablePointer<Memory>) {
        self = from
    }
}
```

which initializes the pointer from another pointer of the *same type*.
Now all your code compiles and works as expected.

What you can do is use `withUnsafeMutablePointer()`:

```
legIntPtr = withUnsafeMutablePointer(&legInt, { $0 })
```

But keep in mind that the compiler does not track this pointer to
the object as a reference and might destroy the object. That's why
these pointers are "unsafe". You should normally use the pointer
only *inside* the `withUnsafeMutablePointer()` closure.

Comment: Is there Apple documentation on `withUnsafeMutablePointer `? It does not seem to be in "The Swift Programming Language" nor "Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective C". Google is being coy...

Comment: @Charlweed: None that I know of. But you can command-click on the function to get its definition with some explaining comments. Or use the auto-generated documentation at http://swiftdoc.org/func/withUnsafeMutablePointer/.