# How to to assign the address of a local swift variable to an UnsafeMutablePointer

Tags: swift

Suppose I have a variable in Swift like

```
var i: CInt = 123;
```

How can I get an `UnsafeMutablePointer<CInt>` to point to the address of `i`?

I know I can pass the address of this variable to a C function `void f(int *i)` by calling

```
f(&i);
```

I also know that a C pointer can be represented in swift as  `UnsafeMutablePointer`. So the question is how can I assign the address of `i` to such an `UnsafeMutablePointer`. I would have expected that something like

```
var p: UnsafeMutablePointer<CInt> = &i;
```

or

```
var p = UnsafeMutablePointer<CInt>(&i);
```

should work, but it doesn't. I guess I could write a C library providing the following function

```
int *noop(int *p){ return p;}
```

which could be used in Swift like

```
var p = noop(&i);
```

but I haven't tried it and it can't be the correct solution. There must be something simpler.

---

And please don't ask why I want to do this. Its more like an academic question to understand the designs of Swift and C interoperability.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29976346/why-can-t-i-initialize-a-swift-unsafemutablepointeruint32-with-myuint32-or.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for [withUnsafeMutablePointer(_: _:)](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_StandardLibrary_Functions/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/func/s:Fs24withUnsafeMutablePointeru0_rFzTRxFzGSpx_q__q_). It takes an inout parameter of type `T` and a block that takes a parameter of type `UnsafeMutablePointer<T>`. It is used as such:

```
var i: Int = 0
withUnsafeMutablePointer(&i) { (pointer) in
    f(pointer)
}
```

Comment: This is the function I was looking for. Would be great though, if you could update your answer in such a way that you initialize `var p: UnsafeMutablePointer<CInt> = nil` first and assign `p = pointer` inside of the closure (instead of calling `f`). Then it would be a direct answer to the question asked. Thanks.

Comment: @dastrobu: Note that using the pointer outside of the withUnsafeMutablePointer closure is unsafe. The pointed-to memory location might become invalid if there are no other references to the variable and  the compiler decides to reuse the memory.

Comment: Good point. Although I doubt that `i` will be reused in this case. But this clarifies why the `withUnsafeMutablePointer` takes the closure, for which there was no obvious reason in the first place to me.